# What is this thing on the corner of the screen?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

There is a weird icon on the corner of my screen, and the number 4. What do they stand for?

[image: The icon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are called Hegemony Credits, and you randomly receive them as drops from bosses. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261550/what-are-hegemony-credits-used-for) for detailed information

Answer (score 2):

This is an indication of how many [Hegemony Credits](http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Pickups#Hegemony_Credits) you have. They are used primarily to unlock new items within the Breach, though they have a few additional uses as well.